# How to install openvpn client in Debian?

Tags: linux, vpn, openvpn, debian-jessie, client-server

I've gone through many tutorials, wiki pages youtube videos about installing. They all are showing how to install openvpn server and use the same with client.

I was using the config files from tcpvpn.com in **Windows** and in **Manjaro**. All I had to do was import the config file and put username and passcode, it would connect and poof internet was working.

I also tried to learn the difference between server and client. All I got was openvpn is community edition? Please help me here, I am struggling to work this out from last 7 to 8 days.

Whenever I import the config files of different countries in network manager it has a blank field of ca.crt, I don't know what to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this should be hard. All there is to do is open a terminal and issue:

```
sudo apt-get install openvpn
```

Then start openvpn with:

```
sudo openvpn --config /path/to/configfile.conf
```

Said config file can be placed anywhere you please, but if it contains references to external files, I suggest placing them all in the same directory and `cd`ing to it before starting openvpn.

Comment: it shows everything ok but internet connection doesn't work. I checked through ifconfig -a, everything is fine but no downlink at all. Thanks

Comment: If OpenVPN shows the message ´Initialization Sequence Completed´, then you are connected, good news. Since you can't yet browse the Internet, there are two more things to check: DNS and routes. First, see if domain name resolution is working by running in a different terminal window ´ping google.com´; if it does not work and instead ´ping 8.8.8.8´ is successful, then you need to specify DNS servers. The other thing is routing: you need to instruct your machine to send traffic through the OpenVPN connection.

Comment: i pinged 8.8.8.8 and it was successful, could you please me with routing - how do i instruct my machine to send traffic though OpenVPN.

Comment: If you can ping 8.8.8.8 then you have Interrnet connectivity. Does ´ping google.com´ work? If not, it's a DNS issue.

Comment: pinging 8.8.8.8 was successful but for "www.google.com" it wasn't. 
I wanna learn how to specify DNS server and routing for OpenVPN. really thanks for helping.

Comment: I did try to search and figure out the solution for specifying DNS server but all I get is for OpenVPN server and client results and I don't know what to do.

Comment: What are the contents of `/etc/resolv.conf`? That is where the DNS servers to be used are stored. To add a DNS server you open `Network Tools`, choose the relevant interface e.g. `Ethernet Interface (eth0)`, click on `Configure`, double click the relevant connection e.g. `Ethernet->Wired connection 1`, click on `IPv4 Settings` and input e.g. `8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4` (for Google's well known DNS servers) in the `Additional DNS servers` field. After a reboot your `/etc/resolv.conf` should contain two additional lines: `nameserver 8.8.8.8` and `nameserver 8.8.4.4'.

Comment: thanks for the big help. Everything is working fine now, though in xubuntu I have to manually edit **/etc/resolv.conf** everytime. 
can you help me one other problem I am facing about easy-tether ? or do I have to ask another question for that query ?

Comment: Did you switch from Debian? In Xubuntu click on the up/down arrow near the top right corner, then click on `Edit connections...`, double-click on `Wired connection 1 -> IPv4 Settings` and edit the `Additional DNS servers` field.

Comment: I never heard of easy-tether so I can't help you on that, but as a general rule you should always ask a new question when you have a new question.

Comment: Shouldn't there be a default config file?

Comment: @Rodrigo The config file contains details about the connection, so it must be specific to it. While it makes little sense to have a *default* configuration, it could be useful to have a *sample* configuration file.