# Setting Open VPN client in debian-9

Tags: linux, networking, debian, vpn, openvpn

I want to set up a VPN client similar to [L2TP VPN - Windows 10 configuration](https://support.untangle.com/hc/en-us/articles/231971387-L2TP-VPN-Windows-10-configuration).

I have installed `openvpn` using

`sudo apt-get install openvpn`

`/etc/openvpn/client.conf` looks like :

```
client
dev tun
port 1194
proto udp

remote 123.456.789.10 1194             
nobind
```

and client configurations taken from [OpenVPN Debian VPN](https://wiki.debian.org/OpenVPN).

`sudo openvpn --config /etc/openvpn/client.conf`

> Options error: You must define CA file (--ca) or CA path (--capath)
>   Use --help for more information.

[Here describes](https://superuser.com/questions/1183305/how-to-install-openvpn-client-in-debian) how to do this, but client configuration file was not listed there.

**I can not take any key or certificate file from my server**. I just want to create simple client just as its in Windows-10.

Comment: Configure your server to use static key instead then

Comment: @TomYan As I mention, I can not do anything to server, actually just an old firewall.

Comment: Well what you want isn't quite logical. It's like "I set up the something with a password but I forgot it and now I just want to disable its password protection but I don't have administration access to it"